# Regex lookaround construct in Java: advise on optimization needed

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to search for filenames in a comma-separated list in:

> text.txt,temp_doc.doc,template.tmpl,empty.zip

I use Java's regex implementation. Requirements for output are as follows:

1. Display only filenames and not their respective extensions
2. Exclude files that begin with "temp_"

It should look like:

> text
>
> template
>
> empty

So far I have managed to write more or less satisfactory regex to cope with the first task:

```
[^\\.,]++(?=\\.[^,]*+,?+)
```

I believe to make it comply with the second requirement best option is to use lookaround constructs, but not sure how to write a reliable and optimized expression. While the following regex does seem to do what is required, it is obviously a flawed solution if for no other reason than it relies on explicit maximum filename length.

```
(?!temp_|emp_|mp_|p_|_)(?<!temp_\\w{0,50})[^\\.,]++(?=\\.[^,]*+,?+)
```

P.S. I've been studying regexes only for a few days, so please don't laugh at this newbie-style overcomplicated code :)

Comment: What are your rules for filenames? Commas are allowed in filenames, so could those occur? In a CSV file, those would be legal if enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Side note: The dot has no special meaning in character classes. You must not escape it there. This `[^\\.,]` will actually disallow the dot, the comma *and the backspace* - which would be a bug.

Comment: @Tomalak - Note that there is also `\\w`, suggesting this comes from a Java string. In that case, `"[^\\.,]"` is the same as `/[^\.,]/`, so the backslash is ignored. I know, small details, but at least no bugs `:)` Still - good comment, most people get this wrong, and that one backslash is useless.

Comment: @Kobi You're right here, but that's nothing to rely on, especially when switching regex dialects often. Sloppy escaping because *"it happens to work"* or *"it does not matter anyway"* is the reason for many software vulnerabilities. Always knowing what level of escaping is required by what part of the environment is crucial.

Comment: @Tomalak - I agree! Everyone is a winner!

Comment: @Kobi Heh :) BTW, Especially PHP makes me crazy with its radically different string parsing depending on whether you use `'` or `"` as the string delimiter. Almost nobody writes PHP regexes that use strictly correct escaping, simply because you would drown in backslashes.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker there are no particular rules applied here as this is just a practice exercise I've made up for myself :)

Comment: @Tomalak good point about escaping dot in chat class, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "\\b        # Start at word boundary\n" +
    "(?!temp_)  # Exclude words starting with temp_\n" +
    "[^,]+      # Match one or more characters except comma\n" +
    "(?=\\.)    # until the last available dot", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

This also allows dots within filenames.

Comment: This is what I acually meant to do in the first place instead alternating combinations of "temp_" - except for I have forgotten that you could actually use word boundary to match comma and a word character. Oh, well... thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4):

> - Display only filenames and not their respective extensions
> - Exclude files that begin with "temp_"

One variant would be like this:

```
(?:^|,)(?!temp_)((?:(?!\.[^.]*(?:,|$)).)+)
```

This allows

- file names that do not begin with a "word character" (Tim Pietzcker's solution does not)
- file names that contain a dot (sth. like `file.name.ext` will be matched as `file.name`)

But actually, this is really complex. You'll be better off writing a small function that splits the input at the commas and strips the extension from the parts.

Anyway, here's the tear-down:

```
(?:^|,)        # filename start: either start of the string or comma
(?!temp_)      # negative look-ahead: disallow filenames starting with "temp_"
(              # match group 1 (will contain your file name)
  (?:          #   non-capturing group (matches one allowed character)
    (?!        #     negative look-ahead (not followed by):
      \.       #       a dot
      [^.]*    #       any number of non-dots (this matches the extension)
      (?:,|$)  #       filename-end (either end of string or comma)
    )          #     end negative look-ahead
    .          #     this character is valid, match it
  )+           #   end non-capturing group, repeat
)              # end group 1
```

http://rubular.com/r/4jeHhsDuJG

Comment: This one is a masterpiece, though it takes quite some time to figure out :)

Comment: @AlexeyDanilov Thanks. :) As I indicated in the answer: Even though many problems *can* be solved by using regex, not all should be. In this case it's smarter to do it without regex altogether. Expressions like this one are much too complex a burden to put onto the maintainer of your code (which might be you, in half a year, after you forgot how it's supposed to work).

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
(?:temp_[^,.]*|([^,.]*))\.[^,]*
```

That pattern will *match* all file names, but will *capture* only valid names.

- If at the current position the pattern can match `temp_file.ext`, it matches it and does not capture.
- It it cannot match `temp_`, it tires to match `([^,.]*)\.[^,]*`, and capture the file's name.

You can see an example here: http://www.rubular.com/r/QywiDgFxww

Comment: something like this crossed my mind at once, but then when calling captured group 1 in a loop output will be: "text null template empty" - which will require another step to get rid of nulls. But in overall it is a nice simple solution.